# Cannot delete files even though I kill the handle

Tags: windows, terminal-services, handle

In Windows Server 2008 R2 which serves as a Terminal Services server I have 50 users.
One of the users has locked a file using a custom built software.
They exit the software (doubled check the process is not running) and I even killed the handle to the file using handle.exe.

Still the file won't be deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but does [Unlocker](http://filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) help?